# Matplotlib scatter plot aligns to right

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a issue plotting with scatter plot hourly and daily data. 
The squares won't align nicely vertically but they are aligned or "tilted" to the right. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

The data has several thousand of these hourly values.

The same happens with just plain plt.scatter(...)

See the link:
[Image available here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cw7x.png)

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
    cmap = plt.cm.jet
    plt.ylim([data.HOUR.min(), data.HOUR.max()])
    plt.xlim([data.index.min(), data.index.max()])
    hours = [(dt.time(i).strftime('%H')) for i in range(24)]
    ax.set_yticks(range(24))
    ax.set_yticklabels(hours, ha="center")
    plt.setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90 )
    scatter = ax.scatter(data.index, data.HOUR, c=np.round(data.A1),
                         s=np.round(data.D1*0.0005), marker='s', cmap=cm, offset_position='screen',
                         rasterized=True, antialiased=True, alpha=0.5, linewidths=0, edgecolor='none')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You should almost never use `set_*ticks` as it de-couples your labels from your data.  What is `data.index`?  I would bet that it is a full data, in which case diagonal lines is correct because you are plotting `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm` against `HH` which gives you a saw-tooth pattern.

Comment: I came up with the solution at the same as you! This fixed the issue: scatter = ax.scatter(testi55.index.date, ... Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Please write that up as an answer.